# How can i simulate a rigid body at micro level using p5.js?

Tags: javascript, physics, p5.js

I just learned that any particle of a rigid body when viewed from another particle's reference frame (of the same body) performs only circular motion, no matter what chaotic path the body is following! So I tried to simulate the same.

I created 100 particles closely located to form a body, and made them follow any arbitrary path , but now i can't get how to stick to one of the particle's reference frame & watch others.
This is what i have done (which i think is of no use):

```js
var path = [];
var particles = [];


class Particle {
  constructor(x_, y_) {
    this.x_ = x_;
    this.y_ = y_;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.pathIndex = 0;

    this.draw = () => {
      fill(360, 100, 100);
      circle(this.x, this.y, 1);
    }

    this.update = () => {
      if (this.pathIndex >= path.length) {
        this.pathIndex = 0;
      } else {
        this.x = (path[this.pathIndex].x + this.x_);
        this.y = (path[this.pathIndex].y + this.y_);
        this.pathIndex++;
      }
      this.draw();
    }
  }
}





function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  colorMode(HSB);

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      particles.push(new Particle(i * 2, j * 2));
    }
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(50);

  fill(0);
  noStroke();
  for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    circle(path[i].x, path[i].y, 5);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
    particles[i].update();

  }
}

function mouseDragged() {
  path.push({
    x: mouseX,
    y: mouseY
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Click and drag to create a path.

For a real rigid body, each particle can have it's own velocity, and i think i can use relative velocity concept to move to a single particle's reference frame & then i can set other's velocity as:
`v(1/2) = v1 - v2`

 Where v1, v2 are there original velocity and v(1/2) is velocity of 1 w.r.t. 2.
But again i don't have any idea to get particle's velocity.

How can i proceed with this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Problem is that particle sees other particles rotating around it if whole rigid body is rotating in a global reference frame (2D plane in your case). Now your rectangle is always directed the same way - so all it's particles will not "feel" any colleague rotation, because there are none.

Comment: It's not necessary that the body should rotate for the particles to see others in circular motion (It can be shown by resolving the velocities of the two particles along the line joining them and perpendicular to it). But I think I should better use matter.js

Comment: You misunderstood rigid body kinematics. Take a look into [this slide](https://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Courses/En4/notes_old/RigidKinematics/rigkin.htm), especially at picture 5.1.5. A point experiences translation `A0A'` and rotation `A'A1` around point B. If rigid body have NOT been rotated, then point B would NOT see A point's rotation around him. Likewise, when we press breaks in a car - all points in a locked wheel can be described only by translation operations. Check [this also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/248612/velocity-of-the-points-of-a-rigid-body?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Typically in visualizing moving objects, we store the object's velocity in variables like v_x, v_y (just like the position itself). Then the update function looks something like this:

```
this.update = () => {
  this.x += this.v_x;
  this.y += this.v_y;
}
```

If the objects velocity can change by a force, then the acceleration (a_x, a_y) should be passed to the update method (or calculated through some other computation) like this:

```
this.update = (a_x, a_y) => {
  this.x += this.v_x;
  this.y += this.v_y;
  this.v_x += a_x;
  this.v_y += a_y;
}
```

In your case however, if I understood your question correctly, there is no need for storing velocities as variables. Therefore you only need to know the `x, y, a` for the whole body, and `x, y` for the particles:

```
const NUM_PARTICLES = 5;
let selectedParticleIdx = 0;
const particle_offsets = [];
let rigidBody;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  rigidBody  = {
    'x': width / 2,
    'y': height / 2,
    'a': 0,
    'width': width / 2,
    'height': height / 2,
  }
  for (let i=0; i < NUM_PARTICLES; i++) {
    let x_offset = random(rigidBody.width) - rigidBody.width / 2;
    let y_offset = random(rigidBody.height) - rigidBody.height / 2;
    particle_offsets.push([x_offset, y_offset]);
  }
}
```

You can also draw the particles along with lines connecting them in order to show the rigidness of the body:

```
function drawBody() {
  push();
  translate(rigidBody.x, rigidBody.y);
  rotate(rigidBody.a);

  // Draw lines
  for (let i = 0; i < NUM_PARTICLES; i++) {
    let particleX1 = particle_offsets[i][0];
    let particleY1 = particle_offsets[i][1];
    for (let j = i + 1; j < NUM_PARTICLES; j++) {
      let particleX2 = particle_offsets[j][0];
      let particleY2 = particle_offsets[j][1];
      line(particleX1, particleY1, particleX2, particleY2);
    }
  }

  // Draw particles
  for (let i = 0; i < NUM_PARTICLES; i++) {
    let particleX = particle_offsets[i][0];
    let particleY = particle_offsets[i][1];
    ellipse(particleX, particleY, 10, 10); // Adjust the size as needed
  }
  pop();
}
```

Now, in order to show the physical concept you just talked about, I suggest showing the particles POV in a box like this:

```
function showParticlePrespective(coef) {
  push();
  translate(280, 10, 80, 100);
  rect(0, 0, 110, 90);
  translate(55, 45);
  rotate(rigidBody.a);
  let mainParticleX = particle_offsets[0][0];
  let mainParticleY = particle_offsets[0][1];

  // Draw particles
  for (let i = 0; i < NUM_PARTICLES; i++) {
    let particleX = particle_offsets[i][0];
    let particleY = particle_offsets[i][1];
    if (i == selectedParticleIdx) {
      fill('red');
    } else {
      fill('white');
    }
    ellipse((particleX - mainParticleX) / coef, (particleY - mainParticleY) / coef, 2, 2); // Adjust the size as needed
  }
  pop();
}
```

Finally in order to move the particle, you can change its x,y,a values in the draw function:

```
function draw() {
  background(100); // Set background color
  drawBody(0);
  rigidBody.x += 0.3;
  rigidBody.y += 0.3;
  rigidBody.a += 0.04;
  showParticlePrespective(3);
}
```

A better way is to let the body change its `x, y, a` values based on user input (keyboard).